# Reading values for CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, string-parsing

I am having some problems getting the row values from the CSV file below

```
CSV
minzoom, maxzoom
0,5
5,10
10,18
```

My Code :

```
i = 0
for line in open("C:/Marine/lookup/distinct_lookup_scales.csv"):
    i = i + 1
    if (i > 1):  #Skip header
        print("Line: " + line)
        #csv_row = line.split(',')
        minzoom = str(line[0])
        maxzoom = str(line[2])
        print("Minzoom:" + minzoom)
        print("Maxzoom:" + maxzoom)
        readShpFile(minzoom, maxzoom)
```

The values returned for **minzoom** and **maxzoom** has been

```
0   5
5   1
1   ,
```

I had used line split but reverted to trying to get items from the line
Not sure if that was the best approach

Comment: What you're reading from csv is a string. Indexing won't work. Split will be a good approach. If you have issues with it, post the output or the issue, or both.

Comment: Have you considered using the csv module for this?

Comment: `minzoom, maxzoom = line.split(',')`?  Indexing doesn't work, as the zoom can be more than 10 which means you need two characters instead of one and you' may need to shift the max zoom location.

Comment: Why don't you directly use pandas data frame's read_csv method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how you should read the csv file.
Take a look at the [csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

One example :

```
import csv

with open('C:/Marine/lookup/distinct_lookup_scales.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csvreader.next() #skip header
    for row in csvreader:
        minzoom = int(row[0])
        maxzoom = int(row[1])
        print('minzoom : {}'.format(minzoom))
        print('maxzoom : {}'.format(maxzoom))
```

You can also use a DictReader which will use your header line to yield dictionaries.

```
import csv

with open('C:/Marine/lookup/distinct_lookup_scales.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        minzoom = int(row['minzoom'])
        maxzoom = int(row['maxzoom'])
        print('minzoom : {}'.format(minzoom))
        print('maxzoom : {}'.format(maxzoom))
```

Comment: Thanks Corentin!. I tried the first way above and the readShpFile method now works as expected!. Thank you so much! Dave

Comment: Thanks also Corentin for the CSV module documentation link, Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try numpy.genfromtxt, like:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("C:/Marine/lookup/distinct_lookup_scales.csv", delimiter = ",",
                     skip_header = 1)
minzooms = data[:,0]
maxzooms = data[:,1]
```

Comment: Thanks Y.Wang. Not used numpy before as I am new to python but will give the approach a try. Dave